# Does any website offer price alerts for open jaw (multi-city) flights?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, online-resources, price, open-jaw

When I'm looking for round-trip tickets in Google Flights, the website allows me to create a price alert for the specified route:

[image: round trip screen]

However, when I change my route to have a return ticket leaving from another city, the option disappears:

[image: open jaw screen]

The same thing happens on other websites (Skyscanner, Momondo...)

Is there any option to set up this kind of alert?

Answer (score 1):

No, such a website doesn't exist as of 2018.

Comment: Oh too bad, thanks for the answer though. Just curious, do you know if there is any technical limitation or it's simply not useful / requested enough to implement?